# ArcMap : Using "near" with python only on objects with the same ID in 2 shp

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, proximity

I want to calculate distance between polygons and points which are in 2 Shapefiles using "near" function in ArcMap.

In my 2 Shapefiles, each point is related to a specific polygon, there is a link using the attributes.

"Near" function seem to calculate the distance between the closest objects (in my case : point to the closest boundary of the polygon) whereas I just want to calculate for each point distance between this point and the closest boundary of THE polygon with THE SAME ID (where point.polygon_id = polygon.id).

```py
import arcpy 
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/data/polypoints.gdb"
## find the nearest polygon from point 
arcpy.Near_analysis('polygon', 'points')
```

What do I add to this Python code to calculate distance only for point and polygon with the same code?

Comment: All tools will process a selection first if one exists. Create a simple loop that selects the polygon and point by their ID then run the near tool.

Comment: @Hornbydd This is not correct for the Near tool... see my explanation in the answer below...

Comment: @JasonMiller, good point about the -1 overwriting, a workaround would be on each loop of the ID, select by ID, run the near tool and write away the connectivity information into a dictionary, clear selection, move onto next ID and repeat. Once all ID's have been processed write the contents of the dictionary back to a dataset which could be the point dataset itself or some other table that could be joined.

Comment: I think what you suggested for a workaround is pretty much what my code does... I was curious if there were "better" ways to do this... (eg. I'm not sure how efficient it is for a large dataset...)

Comment: @JasonMiller, He he.. I should RTFC! Your code is clear, well documented and seems optimal to me. The only tweak I could suggest is that the output of the NEAR tool is written to `in_memory`, you should get a boost in performance with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer by Johannes Lindner given on ESRI community, I used it and did exactly what I needed (@FelixIP it use distanceto, like your answer) :

*It's probably doable with some tool (eg GenerateNearTable and then joining the output to the inputs somehow), but you can also rig up a quick script like this:*

```
in_features = "Points"  # distance field will be added to this fc
near_features = "Polygons"
in_key = "polygon_id"
near_key = "id"
distance_field = "DISTANCE"


# read near_features as dictionary {key: geometry}
near_geometries = {key: shp for key, shp in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(near_features, [near_key, "SHAPE@"])}

# add field to in_features
arcpy.management.AddField(in_features, distance_field, "DOUBLE")

# calculate
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_features, [in_key, distance_field, "SHAPE@"]) as cursor:
    for key, dist, shp in cursor:
        try:
            dist = shp.distanceTo(near_geometries[key])
        except KeyError:
            dist = None
            print(f"key {key} could not be found in {near_features}.")
        cursor.updateRow([key, dist, shp])
```

*Have a great day!
Johannes*

Answer (score 1):

The notion that running the Near tool on selected features will only update values of the selected features is not correct.  In the documentation for the Near tool, it states:

> The input features can be a layer on which you have performed a
> selection. The selected features will be used and updated during the
> execution of the tool. The remaining features will have the values of
> the newly created fields (such as NEAR_FID and NEAR_DIST) set to -1.

This means that when you run the Near tool on selected features, it will (re)set all  non-selected features to -1, which you don't want.

The code below works but  I have no idea how it would run on a large dataset (I tested with just 9 polygons and 11 point features that I manually created for testing).

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/data/polypoints.gdb"

fc_polygons = "C:/data/polypoints.gdb/polygons"
fc_points = "C:/data/polypoints.gdb/points"

listOfPolygonIds = set(row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc_polygons, "IdField"))
dictOutput = {}

for polygonId in listOfPolygonIds:
    ## Using only this code does not work because when you updated the selected records, it resets all the other non-selected records to -1
    # sel_polygons = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc_polygons, "NEW SELECTION", '"IdField" = ' + str(polygonId))
    # sel_points = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc_points, "NEW SELECTION", '"PolygonIdField" = ' + str(polygonId))
    # arcpy.Near_analysis(sel_polygons[0], sel_points[0])

    # Use this code instead (first part is repeat of above code, but with additional steps...)
    sel_polygons = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc_polygons, "NEW SELECTION", '"IdField" = ' + str(polygonId))
    sel_points = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc_points, "NEW SELECTION", '"PolygonIdField" = ' + str(polygonId))
    output = arcpy.Near_analysis(sel_polygons[0], sel_points[0])

    # Add the NEAR_FID and NEAR_DIST values to a dictonary to be used in the UpdateCursor below
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(output, ["NEAR_FID", "NEAR_DIST"]) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            dictOutput[polygonId] = [row[0], row[1]]

# Loop through each record in the polygons layer and update the NEAR_FID and NEAR_DIST fields with values from the dictonary populated above
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc_polygons, ["IdField", "NEAR_FID", "NEAR_DIST"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = dictOutput[row[0]][0]
        row[2] = dictOutput[row[0]][1]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

An additional note: This code assumes that each Polygon feature has a unique id in the "IdField" that's being used.  The code below won't work without some adjustments if there are, say, two polygons with the value of 6 in the "IdField"...

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with field calculator, e.g.

```
d = {}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("POINTS",("ID", "Shape@" )) as cursor:
 for fid,point in cursor:d[fid]=point
def getD(id,pgon):
 return d[id].distanceTo(pgon)
#-----
getD( !ID!, !Shape! )
```

On Distance field in polygons table, but using out of the box tools is a much better option.

So run generate near table tool with very large search distance and remove unmatched pairs. You can even visualize results it if you run tool with 'location' checked.

[image]